# Remove article title alias from URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Need to remove article alias from URL using htaccess rewrite module.

**Current URL`s format**

/software/graphics/editors/901-artweaver

/software/graphics/editors/901-artweaver?info=audit

**Should look like shown below**

/software/graphics/editors/901

/software/graphics/editors/901?info=audit

Comment: Are you using Joomla CMS?

Comment: The logic that creates such URLs is located in components/com_content/router.php so you might want to check it out to avoid being dependent on Apache mod_rewrite module, but rather to create SEF URLs correctly in the first place. I'm not sure what are the proper steps to override the core router.php for 1.5 but I'm sure it's a trivial thing for 2.5 and 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works only in the `/software/graphics/editors/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^software/graphics/editors/(\d+)(-[\w-]+)?$ /software/graphics/editors/$1 [QSA]
```

To make it work in other directories use e.g.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([\w/]+\d+)(-[\w-]+)?$ /$1 [QSA]
```

The second one is not 100% sure to work, but it should.